# ListView item doesn't inflate to wrap content as intended, height == 0 but shouldn't

Tags: android, android-listview, layout-inflater

I am trying to incorporate 2 lists "sections" into a LinearLayout via height weights. The issue that I am having is that, though the container for the "section" is displayed with the proper height (where the background is `sub_gray`), and the adapter count is correct, the height of my actual list rows is 0 which makes my list appear invisible.

**LIST ITEM**

Below is the code that my list rows/items directly work with. `To avoid the wall of code getting too long, I will include my code for one of the lists seeing as they are both behaving the same.`

*layout_quick_guide_checklist_item*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.my_project.project.QuickGuideChecklistListItemView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:background="@color/sub_gray"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_checklist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:checked="true"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_field"
        style="@style/default_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="@string/height_wrap_string"/>

</com.my_project.project.QuickGuideChecklistListItemView>
```

*QuickGuideChecklistListItemView*

```
public class QuickGuideChecklistListItemView extends LinearLayout{

    private TextView listText;

    public QuickGuideChecklistListItemView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public QuickGuideChecklistListItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public QuickGuideChecklistListItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public static QuickGuideChecklistListItemView inflate(ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        QuickGuideChecklistListItemView itemView = (QuickGuideChecklistListItemView) 
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_quick_guide_checklist_item, parent, false);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInflate(){
        super.onFinishInflate();        
        listText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_field);
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        listText.setText(text);
    }
}
```

**COMPLETE LIST**

Now I take the above code and use it within my activity to create a list (recall; there are actually two lists in my activity, constructed similarly, and both resulting in row heights of 0).

*QuickGuideDetailActivity*

```
public class QuickGuideDetailActivity extends NavigationDrawerActivity implements OnClickListener{

    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    private QuickGuideModel selectedQuickGuide;
    private QuickGuideChecklistAdapter checklistAdapter;
    private QuickGuideTipAdapter tipsAdapter;
    private TextView quickGuidesTitle, quickGuidesDescription, inflaterButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        selectedQuickGuide = QuickGuidesActivity.selectedQuickGuide;    
        buildLists();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutId(){
        return R.layout.sub_activity_quick_guide;
    }

    public void checkAdapterSize(View v){
        String checklistString = (checklistAdapter == null)? "null": "" + checklistAdapter.getCount();
        String tipString = (tipsAdapter == null)? "null": "" + tipsAdapter.getCount();
        Toast.makeText(this, checklistString + " : " + tipString,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void buildLists(){
        TextView checklistTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checklist_title_bar);
        checklistTitle.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.title_checklist));

        ArrayList<String> checklistStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Object guide : selectedQuickGuide.checklist){
            checklistStrings.add((String) guide.toString());
        }
        checklistAdapter = new QuickGuideChecklistAdapter(checklistStrings);
        ListView checklist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.checklist_list);
        checklist.setAdapter(checklistAdapter);
        Log.d(TAG, "List Size - Checklist = " + selectedQuickGuide.checklist.length);


        TextView tipsTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tips_title_bar);
        tipsTitle.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.title_tips));

        tipsAdapter = new QuickGuideTipAdapter(selectedQuickGuide.topTips);
        ListView tips = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tips_list);
        tips.setAdapter(tipsAdapter);
        Log.d(TAG, "List Size - Tips = " + selectedQuickGuide.topTips.length);

    }
}
```

*sub_activity_quick_guide*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/default_container"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/expandable_section"
            layout="@layout/section_expandable_details" />

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/default_container" 
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:weightSum="2">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/checklist_section"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@color/sub_gray" 
                android:onClick="checkAdapterSize" >

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp" />

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/checklist_title_bar"
                    style="@style/default_label_text_view"
                    android:background="@color/random_blue" 
                    android:text="@string/loading" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/checklist_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    android:divider="@color/off_white"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tips_list_section"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:background="@color/sub_gray" 
                android:onClick="checkAdapterSize" >

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp" />

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/tips_title_bar"
                    style="@style/default_label_text_view"
                    android:background="@color/random_blue" 
                    android:text="@string/loading" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/tips_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    android:divider="@color/off_white"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_list_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*QuickGuideChecklistAdapter*

```
public class QuickGuideChecklistAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private ArrayList<String> guides;
    private List<Boolean> checklistItemTicked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    public QuickGuideChecklistAdapter(ArrayList<String> guides){
        this.guides = guides;
        for(int i = 0; i < guides.size(); i++)
            checklistItemTicked.add(false);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return guides.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        if(position < 0 || position >= guides.size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Position is out of range of list with size " + guides.size());
        return guides.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        QuickGuideChecklistListItemView itemView = (QuickGuideChecklistListItemView)convertView;
        if (null == itemView)
            itemView = QuickGuideChecklistListItemView.inflate(parent);

        itemView.setText(guides.get(position));
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Setting text to " + guides.get(position) + " in position " + position);

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Sorry for the wall of code, but I have tried adjusting everything and just can't seem to get anything to work. So just as a final bit:

1. The adapters are set, getCount() returns the valid count of items in the list and clicking on the layouts in order to call checkAdapterSize() also results in a Toast with the proper values.
2. The first view is "inflated" but results in a view height of 0.
3. The container layouts for my list "sections" (checklist_section in sub_activity_quick_guide for example) have a height which can be seen by the sub_gray background.

I have tried changing height attributes from match_parent to wrap_content and vice versa with no luck. I have tried explicitly declaring a minHeight for my list items and all that good stuff. I just can't seem to ever get a list row item to actually inflate.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny how I always manage to figure out an answer to my own questions right after I post a question on SO after days of trying :P

Anyway, `the issue was in placing my ListViews inside of LinearLayouts with heights determined by weight.` I removed the LinearLayout wrappers for my "sections" and applied the weights to my ListViews directly, voila... good to go.

**New complete working Activity layout**

*sub_activity_quick_guide*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/default_container"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/expandable_section"
            layout="@layout/section_expandable_details" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checklist_title_bar"
            style="@style/default_label_text_view"
            android:background="@color/random_blue"
            android:text="@string/loading" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/checklist_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="@color/off_white"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tips_title_bar"
            style="@style/default_label_text_view"
            android:background="@color/random_blue"
            android:text="@string/loading" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/tips_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="@color/off_white"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_list_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Hope it helps someone in the future, didn't realize weights would mess with it like that but apparently ListViews don't like weighted containers.